# How to convert DataGridViewRowCollection to DataRow[]

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to convert `DataGridViewRowCollection` to `DataRow[]`
Is there any way like:

```
 DataRow[] rowarray=(DataRow[])(datagridview.Rows);
```

Or do I have to convert each row using `foreach`?

Comment: For what purpose? Do you really think this is a question?

Comment: how did you create the data grid view? please provide more information...

Comment: @YuliamChandra I just added it from Toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to a DataTable first.

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(datagridview.DataSource);
```

Then copy the rows into a DataRow array.

```
DataRow[] drArray = new DataRow[data.Rows.Count];
data.Rows.CopyTo(drArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about with Linq?

```
DataRow[] rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                   .Select(r => r.DataBoundItem as DataRowView)
                                   .Where(drv => drv != null)
                                   .Select(drv => drv.Row)
                                   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. Try it and let us know.

```
void covertDGVToRowColl()
{
    DataRow[] rowColl = new DataRow[dgTemp.Rows.Count]; //dgTemp is the datagridview
    DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn in dgTemp.Columns)
    {
        dtTable.Columns.Add(dgvColumn.Name);
    }
    DataRow newRow;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dRow in dgTemp.Rows)
    {
        newRow = dtTable.NewRow();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn in dgTemp.Columns)
        {
            newRow[dgvColumn.Name] = dRow.Cells[dgvColumn.Name].Value;
        }
        rowColl[i] = newRow;
        ++i;
    }
}
```